# Why isn't stripping x-frame options allowing me to load a cross site iframe in this extension?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, content-security-policy, content-script

### Context

I'm building a chrome extension that allows users to run automated scripts on 3rd party sites from anywhere on the web.  The extension needs the ability to dynamically insert an iframe on any page that the user in on where that iframe is loading a 3rd party site.

### The Problem

When I try to load linkedin.com in an iframe from google.com I get the linkedin.com refused to connect. If I look I can see that the x-frame options are still present in the headers while I have confirmed that I've stripped them out in them out.

**I've added the following to my extension background script to allow iframes to load in any site**

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {
    const headers = details.responseHeaders.filter(header => {
        let headerName = header.name.toLowerCase();
        return !(headerName === 'content-security-policy' || headerName === 'x-frame-options');
    })
    if (details.url.includes('linkedin.com')) {
        // this console log shows that I've stripped out the necessary headers correctly
        console.debug('REMOVED HEADERS: ', headers);
    }
    return {
        responseHeaders: headers
    };
}, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>']
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

**I'm using the following code in the console on google.com to insert an iframe loading linkedin.com**

```
(function () {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    iframe.style.zIndex = 100000;
    iframe.style.top = 0;
    iframe.style.left = 0;
    iframe.height = 600;
    iframe.width = 900;
    iframe.referrerPolicy = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
    iframe.src = 'https://www.linkedin.com';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

**Here you can see the console log showing the modified headers with x-frame and CSP removed from the iframe request headers**
[image]

**but then the iframe doesn't load. it returns 200 but nothing happens**
[image]

Comment: Could be another extension that changes the headers which wins because it was installed earlier. Otherwise it sounds like a bug. Try adding 'extraHeaders' in the last parameter of addListener.

Comment: @wOxxOm didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This actually was working and the Brave shield was preventing the iframe from loading in the page.